# How to calculate permutations?

Tags: permutations, combinations

I'm trying to figure out all possible permutations/combinations of an idea in my head.

Say I start with 60 objects. I can use anywhere between 1 and 24 of those objects to create a pattern. The objects can be arranged in any order in this pattern, but within the limitations of 1 being the minimum objects used and 24 being the maximum.

How many patterns could I make total and how would I calculate it?

Comment: Does the order of objects in the pattern matter?  For example, is the pattern AB the same as the pattern BA, or are those two different patterns?

Comment: AB is different than BA, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If objects are distinguishable, then don't you think the answer will be the summation of ${60\choose1}\cdot1!+{60\choose2}\cdot2!+\dots+{60\choose24}\cdot24!$

Thanks

Satish

Comment: That worked perfectly.

And in case anyone was interested, the sum is equal to:

4,818,692,886,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000

Or, in text:

four tredecillion, 
eight hundred eighteen duodecillion, 
six hundred ninety-two undecillion, 
eight hundred eighty-six decillion

Comment: You are welcome!